# Conservar model attributes entre llamadas Spring + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Necesito mostrar en una página información relativa a un objeto, separando ésta información en pestañas, tal y como lo tengo montado la aplicación hace una única llamada a la BD, carga toda la información en un atributo del modelo y carga la página.

El problema está en que no sé como propagar este objeto ya cargado cuando el usuario hace click en otra pestaña, ya que esto volvería al controller en "/products", por ejemplo, pero el atributo ya no está.

No me gustaría tener que volver a cargar la información desde BD cada vez que se cambia de pestaña ni almacenar el objeto en sesión, ya que no quiero que permanezca tanto, sólo que se lo vayan pasando de una llamada a otra dentro de estas pestañas.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto?

Mi controller

```
@Controller
public class CompanyTokenController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CompanyTokenRepository repository;
    
    @GetMapping()
    String loadTokenByTab(@RequestParam Long id, final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("company", repository.findOneWithRelationsById(id));
        return "company";
    }

    @GetMapping("/company")
    String loadCompanyTab() {
        return "company";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    String loadProductsTab() {
        return "products";
    }
```

El template

```
        <nav id="nav">
            <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" th:text="#{company}"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" th:href="@{products}" th:text="#{products}"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" th:href="@{downloads}" th:text="#{downloads}"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" th:href="@{announcement}" th:text="#{announcementBoard}"></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" th:href="@{contact}" th:text="#{contact}"></a>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo, dices que si el usuario toca en la pestaña Products, hace una petición a la ruta /products y carga los datos en esa pestaña solamente. Luego toca en Company, y se cargan los datos de la pestaña Company. Pero si luego el usuario vuelve a tocar en Products, lo que quieres es que no se cargue de nuevo los datos de Products desde la BD porque ya están en la página. Es eso?

Comment: Tengo un objeto Company, que dentro tiene List<Product>, List<Download> etc, la primera vez que se entra a la página (por /company?id=x) cargo toda la info en este objeto que ya lo tiene todo dentro, la cosa es, al cambiar de pestaña (con los href que llevan a /products, /downloads, etc) seguir manteniendo de alguna manera este objeto company que ya tenía cargado con toda la info que me sigue haciendo falta mientras esté mostrando las pestañas.

Comment: No me queda claro si al cargar por primera vez la pestaña Company se cargan todas las demás pestañas (por lo que dices parecería que sí, pero entonces para qué está el endpoint /product ?)
De cualquier manera, eso lo puedes manejar en el front end, si ya tienes los datos cargados, antes de hacer la petición verificas si esos datos están (por ejemplo con un flag que hayas colocado previamente el cargar los datos por primera vez), y si ya tienes los datos entonces cancelas el submit. Puedes usar onClick() en cada una de los links de las pestañas para decidir si se envían los datos o no.

Comment: El contenido de cada pestaña está en un .html distinto, al carga por primera vez se carga la info de todas las pestañas en el susodicho objeto pero solo se carga la pestaña de company. No es que al hacer el submit no sepa si enviar los datos o no, es que al enlazar al controlador desde los href ese objeto, que solo vive lo que dura la request, ya no sigue activo en esta segunda petición.